# Safari Remote Debugging Breaks my responsive design

Tags: ios, css, debugging, sass, safari

my website has a responsive design that is perfectly rendered in all devices. However it doesn't work when I use Safari's remote debugging. These are the steps to reproduce the error:

1. I open my site from my iPhone's Safari and it looks as expected.
2. The site also works fine in a mobile size using Desktop Chrome, Firefox and Safari.
3. I plug my iPhone to the Mac and inspect the website using Safari's remote debugging inspector: Safari > Develop > My Iphone > www.mysite.com Immediately the iPhone renders a wrong design. Elements don't respect their CSS size settings.
4. I close the inspector and reload the site from the iPhone and the site is rendered perfectly.
   [image]

I have the viewport settings:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

I have tried other alternatives but this does not seem to be the problem. I use SASS and my CSS files are minified. I suspect that there's  something wrong related to SASS.

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to Mojave and the error has been fixed. I guess that something was wrong in my Safari.